# Where is the quest log?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

My son is currently trying to get back to Pokemon Y on its 3DS and since he did not play the game for a long time, he can't remember what he is supposed to do and turns around endlessly in the same locations, hoping something happens.

I thought I could help him by looking at the quest log but I can't find where it is located.

So, do anyone know where the quest log is in Pokemon X/Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no quest log or journal item in Pokemon X and Y.

There was an item in Diamond, Pearl, and Platinum called the [Journal](http://serebii.net/itemdex/journal.shtml). This item recorded things you had done including places you went, Pokemon you caught, and trades you made. If you hadn't played the game in the past two days, the journal would automatically open when you resumed your save game.

<strike>I believe Ruby, Sapphire, and Emerald</strike> Fire Red and Leaf Green had a similar feature that showed things you did before letting you resume, but I haven't found a source to confirm this yet, and unfortunately I no longer own these games to test it. (Thanks to jwodder on correcting me here)